# Rails: Why is 'rake secret' giving me an error?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run the `rake secret` command when I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::SECURE_CONNECTION
/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/config/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/config/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

I've got the latest version of mysql and the gem mysql2. Has anyone else stumbled upon this issue recently? Most posts on this topic I've found here are some five years old and doesn't fix this problem.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/603

Comment: My guess is that your mysql2 is gem is incompatible with the version of mysql.  Could you give the exact version numbers of each that you're using?

Comment: gem version is 0.3.18 and my mysql version is Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.10, for osx10.10 (x86_64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here. This problem was caused by a mismatch between the mysql2 gem version (0.3.18) and the version specified in the gemfile (0.3.16).